# Deployment process (.bpmn) to Camunda Engine

Tags: deployment, workflow, camunda

Good afternoon!
Could you help me, how to properly deploy an XML process in .bpmn format to Camunda Engine.

I found the API method POST /deployment/create
It should be multipart -format request.

Could someone show me the example how the request-json should looks like? I want to understand how the headers and body will be filled.

Another question:deploymentName is the same as processName?

Answer (score 1):

You don't send JSON for deployment.Here is one example.

[image]

Camunda does support open api . You can read this link
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/openapi/

You can even extract(by unzipping) the open api json from the jar mentioned in link and import in Postman for exploring all Camunda rest apis.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the REST api directly, you could use an existing client
(e.g. https://camunda-community-hub.github.io/camunda-platform-7-rest-client-spring-boot/snapshot/user-guide/examples.html#usage-of-feign-clients)
or generate your client from the openapi specification (see https://github.com/berndruecker/camunda-7-openapi-demo).
This will make it easier to call the REST api (and also there you can find how to call it directly if you really want to).

And regarding the deployment name, it's something different than the process name. A deployment can contain multiple processes. The name can be seen in the cockpit, if you look at the deployments.